# importrange query with order by and nulls

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using `Importrange` to bring data from another google sheet and then querying it to remove blank rows and want to order my data by certain standards. I've run into a problem with null values as they go to the top when ordering but I want them to go to the bottom (yet using ascending order).

I've already tried every possible solution from the internets I could find like using `isnull`, `isblank` and others but nothing seems to do the trick.

```
=query(importrange("google sheet", "Sheet!A2:L20"), "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col4, Col7, Col6")
```

This is the query I am currently using which obviously is not working as the null values have "lower" value than any other number in the system.

Any help from you guys?

Comment: Unfortunately not and apparently this forum does not support any convenient way to paste tables here.

Comment: no need to paste tables. just paste a link and enable **view** in sharing (green button)